# React: Events and Router not working in a specific code segment

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router, dom-events

There's a specific segment of JSX code in my React project where both events and router don't work.

**PhotoFrame.tsx:**

```
const PhotoFrame = ({ photoId }: PhotoFrameProps) => {
    const photo = useAppSelector((state: RootState) =>
        selectPhotoById(state, photoId)
    );
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const url = photo.urls.regular;
    const author = photo.user.name;
    const authorUsername = photo.user.username; 
    const path = `/user/${authorUsername}`;
    const authorPhotoUrl = photo.user.profile_image.small;

    return (
        <article className="frame-container" >
             {/* <Link to={path}>{author}</Link> */}  ----> THIS IS THE LAST PLACE IN CODE WHERE LINK WORKS
            <div className="frame">
            {/* <Link to={path}>{author}</Link> */} ----> DOESN'T WORK
                <img
                    src={url}
                    alt={`Photography by ${author}`}
                />
                <address className="author">
                    <img src={authorPhotoUrl} alt="Author" />
                    <Link to={path}>{author}</Link>  ----> DOESN'T WORK (THIS IS THE ORIGINAL PLACEMENT OF LINK)
                </address>
            </div>
            {/* <Link to={path}>{author}</Link> */} ----> DOESN'T WORK
        </article>
    );
};
```

`a` element is rendered in DOM, but clicking on it does absolutely nothing. There's no change in URL, no errors or any other behavior.

[DOM screenshot of a PhotoFrame instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/256xh.png)

At first I thought the issue was related to the router/Link element alone. I added an `onClick` event to the `address` element and used `useNavigate` hook from the router inside of the event handler to see if it would work - this is when I discovered that my event also isn't being fired. I tried to change `address` to different elements, but nothing changed. Event isn't fired even if I put a `button` instead of `address`.

**PhotoFrame.tsx with event handler:**

```
    const handleAddressClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement> = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("CLICK");   ---> NOT LOGGED IN THE CONSOLE
        navigate(path);  
    };

    return (
        <article className="frame-container" >
            <div className="frame">
                <img
                    src={url}
                    alt={`Photography by ${author}`}
                />
                <address className="author" onClick={handleAddressClick}>
                    <img src={authorPhotoUrl} alt="Author" />
                </address>
            </div>
        </article>
    );
```

Comment: It's nothing about React and its router themselves but some issues with the style layout, specifically, with your pseudo as `::before` and `::after` that have the absolute position. Moreover, the element with the lamp is hovering over frames.

Comment: I suspect this is a CSS/HTML DOM issue where there may be some element overlaying the image area that makes it *not clickable*. Can you [edit] to include your css and complete component code for a more complete [mcve]? Think you could also create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue we could inspect live?

Comment: @FoxAmadeus Oh my god, you're absolutely right! Removing position absolute from the  pseudo-elements instantly resolved the issue. I feel so silly that it never crossed my mind. Thank you for your help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DrewReese you're right as well, CSS was the issue. It never occurred to me that could be the cause because I never encountered this issue before. I'll edit the question now to include the problematic CSS. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, what tipped me off was seeing those pseudo elements, and no worries, we've all been there. Do you still need help with this as a problem to solve, or have you effectively been unblocked and moving on?

Comment: @DrewReese In retrospection, it should've occurred to me to inspect CSS because it was too odd for "router and events" not to work in such a small chunk of code. The issue is resolved, I'm moving on to finding an entirely new way of achieving the same layout without ruining the functionalities haha. I'm still a beginner, but now I know for any future cases. Thank you for being kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the `position: absolute` set on pseudo-elements. It overlays them over the `Link` and `address` elements, making them unreachable/unclickable.

```
.frame::before, .frame::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
}
```

In addition, there is a flex container at the bottom of the page which overlays chunks of PhotoFrame instances when scrolling, once again making the `Link`s unreachable in that area.

Two solutions which don't require changing the layout:

1. Add add `pointer-events: none;` to all of the pseudo-elements and elements which are overlaying the interactive elements (if they don't require any mouse interaction themselves).
2. Add `position: relative` and `z-index` to elements which should respond to mouse/pointer events, where the `value` of `z-index` is higher than that of an overlay.